# Synchronizing events / data in java swing between many different classes

Tags: java, swing

My question is conceptual about synchronizing data and events in programming a gui. (This example shows batch state being the facilitator of taking classes that implement the same interface and dynamical updating cells in two different frames.This code is where I got my idea. )

I am assuming that I will create new instances of this batch state object specifically in the classes where an event is triggered(panel)  and the reaction  to that event(another panel) . I will do this by adding the classes that need to communicate to the a list of bsListeners. Then call the batch state function like "setSelectedCell()" to iterate over each class to synchronize them.

**The Problem**
This would work perfect if the object both shared the same arrayList but since they are both new instances they don't. I tried changing things to static and it is freaking out especially in the interface. Is this approach logical I am brand new to programming gui's? Sorry this is a novel.

```
interface BatchStateListener {

    public void valueChanged(Cell cell, String newValue);

    public void selectedCellChanged(Cell newSelectedCell)
}

class BatchState {

    private String[][] values;
    private Cell selectedCell;
    private List<BatchStateListener> listeners;

    public BatchState(int records, int fields) {
        values = new String[records][fields];
        selectedCell = null;
        listeners = new ArrayList<BatchStateListener>();
    }

    public void addListener(BatchStateListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void setValue(Cell cell, String value) {

        values[cell.record][cell.field] = value;

        for (BatchStateListener l : listeners) {
            l.valueChanged(cell, value);
        }
    }

    public String getValue(Cell cell) {
        return values[cell.record][cell.field];
    }

    public void setSelectedCell(Cell selCell) {

        selectedCell = selCell;

        for (BatchStateListener l : listeners) {
            l.selectedCellChanged(selCell);
        }
    }

    public Cell getSelectedCell() {
        return selectedCell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My questions was a bit confusing, but I came to my answer. I was just wondering how to implement this BatchState class in my code. I found that if I make it in main and pass it to the constructors frames/panels that need to communicate with each other they all can share reference to it.